# xmlhttp is not defined

Tags: javascript, ajax, request

Estou tendo alguns problemas ao realizar uma requisição ajax pelo javascript, porém, fica aparecendo que a variável `xmlhttp` não foi definida, mesmo eu definindo ela antes da função e antes de usar ela. Como resolver ?

```
var xmlhttp;
function generateMessage(){
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = callbackChampMessage();
    var url = "randomName.php";
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
};
function callbackChampMessage(){
    if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
        var messageHeader = document.querySelector("#champ-message");
        champMessage.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    };
};
```

- Dando um console.log(xmlhttp) recebo os valores todos zerados ou nulos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema é que você está criando uma variável local em `generateMessage`, por isso ela não está atribuindo o valor a variável global.

Quando você define uma variável dentro do escopo da função ou redeclarada ela, ela passa a ser local, não podendo ser acessada fora da função.

```
// Global
var global = 0;

function myFunc() {
    // O js cria uma variável local
    var global = 3;
}

myFunc();
console.log( global ); //Output: 0
```

Outro erro é que você, ao invés de atribuir a função `callbackChampMessage` em `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange`, está chamando a função antes mesmo da requisição ser aberta.

Para atribuir uma função é necessário passar apenas o nome dela.

Exemplo:

```
var xmlhttp;

function generateMessage(){

    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = callbackChampMessage;
    var url = "https://example.com/";
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();

};

function callbackChampMessage(){
    console.log( xmlhttp );

    if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
        var messageHeader = document.querySelector("#champ-message");
        champMessage.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    } else {
        alert( "Ready State: " + xmlhttp.readyState );
        alert( "Status: " + xmlhttp.status );
        alert( "Status: " + xmlhttp.responseURL );
    }
};
```

Comment: então, agora parou de apresentar erros, mas continua não funcionando :/

Comment: Pode ser que o `status code` de sua página seja diferente de `200 OK`. Adicione, na função `callbackChampMessage`, um `console.log(xmlhttp);` antes do `if`.

Comment: @MuriloGambôa, editei minha resposta. Passou batido anteriormente.

Comment: Apenas remover os parenteses da chamada do callback funcionou, eu havia visto esse erro e me esqueci de remover